# How to make excel interpret Chinese characters in CSV file

Tags: shell-script, csv, sendmail

I am sending a report from a unix shell script that contains chinese characters.

When I open the CSV report in plaintext editor like textmate I can see the chinese characters but when I open CSV report file in Excel I don't see the chinese characters, but some gibberish.

How do I "tell" excel that the file contains Chinese charset ?

Here is the code that sends mail and attaches the CSV file.

```
send_mail() {

v_mailpart="ZZ_/afg6432dfgkl.94531q"
echo "Mail to be sent to $RPT_SEND_TO"
echo "To: $RPT_SEND_TO
Subject: Blah Report as of $report_date_format;
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$v_mailpart\"
MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--$v_mailpart
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body><p>Hi All,<p>Please find attached, the daily report <p>Thanks,
<br/>Blah Team</br/><br/><br/></p><p>NOTE: This is an auto-generated email. Do not reply to it. Please send an email to blah-group@mycompany.com in
 case of any issues.<p></body></html>

--$v_mailpart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:UTF-8;
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"UTF-8\";
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blah-report.csv
`cat $spool_file5`" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
}
```

Comment: Try prepending a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the original csv. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: This question might get better results on [SU].  anu: if nothing happens here in the next 48 hours, I suggest that you click "flag" → "in need of moderator intervention" and ask to have the question migrated to [SU].  Please *do not* just re-ask the same question there.

Comment: @cdosborn I am using Excel 2011 for mac. Having a hard time adding BOM to the start. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Try this `{ printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF'; cat file; } > file.new`

Comment: @cdosborn still no luck. i can see the BOM in vi and verified that the Octal is correct. But, excel still refuses to understand that the file is utf-8 and has chinese in it.

Comment: What is the output of `file yourCsv.csv`, before/after the BOM

Comment: @cdosborn content partial before (as seen in vi):: `\346\235\255\345\267\236,2,4` after :: `\357\273\277\346\235\255\345\267\236,2,4`  `\357\273\277` are the octal for utf-8 BOM. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Run my previous comment in osx terminal. Run it on the original CSV, and post the output.